# How to remove App title from Navigation Drawer Layout?

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove the app title which is on the imageView? I use the Navigation Drawer Layout.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `setTitle(null)` at `onCreate` from the activity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465555/hiding-scrolling-activity-title-in-android-studio this will help

Comment: add your xml file here.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Thanks a lot..

Comment: @Tipu No problem. I made an answer so you can accept mine answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its should be something like that

in activity set on `onCreate()`

```
setTitle(" ");
```

OR if you use CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) 
                               findViewById(R.id.your_id);
toolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
```

OR in fragment on `onCreateView()`

```
getActivity().setTitle(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the activity's title, you should remove it by calling `setTitle(null)` at `onCreate` method